# Flutter - how to get Text widget on widget test

Tags: testing, flutter

I'm trying to create a simple widget test in Flutter. I have a custom widget that receives some values, composes a string and shows a Text with that string. I got to create the widget and it works, but I'm having trouble reading the value of the Text component to assert that the generated text is correct.

I created a simple test that illustrates the issue. I want to get the text value, which is "text". I tried several ways, if I get the finder asString() I could interpret the string to get the value, but I don't consider that a good solution. I wanted to read the component as a Text so that I have access to all the properties.

So, how would I read the Text widget so that I can access the data property?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('my first widget test', (WidgetTester tester) async {

    await tester
        .pumpWidget(MaterialApp(home: Text("text", key: Key('unit_text'))));

    // This works and prints: (Text-[<'unit_text'>]("text"))
    var finder = find.byKey(Key("unit_text"));
    print(finder.evaluate().first);

    // This also works and prints: (Text-[<'unit_text'>]("text"))
    var finderByType = find.byType(Text);
    print(finderByType.evaluate().first);

    // This returns empty
    print(finder.first.evaluate().whereType<Text>());

    // This throws: type 'StatelessElement' is not a subtype of type 'Text' in type cast
    print(finder.first.evaluate().cast<Text>().first);

  });
}
```

Comment: Where in your code is `find` coming from

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I got it working. I had to access the widget property of the Element, and then cast it as text:

```
var text = finder.evaluate().single.widget as Text;
print(text.data);
```

Comment: You probably want a `whereType<Text>()` instead of a cast

Comment: `whereType<Text>()` won't work, since you iterate not over `Text`s, but `StatelessWidgets`. You need to access `.widget` property to get `Text`

Comment: To elaborate a bit more I ended up using:

final fieldWidget = find.byType(TextField).evaluate().first.widget;
final fieldTextValue = (fieldWidget as TextField).controller?.text;

Comment: I just needed the `(.... as Text).data` part of this answer.

Answer (score 28):

Please check this simple example.

```
testWidgets('Test name', (WidgetTester tester) async {

// finding the widget
var textFind = find.text("text_of_field");

// checking widget present or not
expect(textFind, findsOneWidget);

// getting Text object
Text text = tester.firstWidget(textFind);

// validating properties
expect(text.style.color, Colors.black);
...
...

}
```

Comment: the undersading of textFind which is a Finder and tester.firstWidget which is a Widget helped me to understand this important, but simple fact

Answer (score 6):

You can use `find.text`

https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/testing/widget/finders#1-find-a-text-widget

```
testWidgets('finds a Text Widget', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  // Build an App with a Text Widget that displays the letter 'H'
  await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Text('H'),
    ),
  ));

  // Find a Widget that displays the letter 'H'
  expect(find.text('H'), findsOneWidget);
});
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this approach. Consider my example: I'm making a simple game in flutter and in my tests, I'm checking that text `1` is present on the screen. I might have multiple 1s on the screen, but not the desired. The test will pass in that case. What I really want is to make sure the text for a **specific element** is as expected. Thus I'm using `find.byKey(Key('Health'))` and in production code I write `Text(myHealth, key: Key('Health'))`