# Unable to find TextField text data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm trying to write a test for a `TextField` where I'm using an `IconButton` as the TextField's `suffixIcon` so that, when pressed, it will toggle the TextField's `obscureText` property. The widget itself works as expected, but I'm having a difficult time approaching the tests.

Code samples:

**password_field.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/util/app_theme.dart';
import 'package:app/widgets/inputs/text_validator.dart';

class PasswordField extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool showValidator;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final String errorText;

  PasswordField({
    this.errorText,
    @required this.onChanged,
    this.showValidator = true,
  });

  @override
  _PasswordFieldState createState() => _PasswordFieldState();
}

class _PasswordFieldState extends State<PasswordField> {
  String _password;
  bool _shouldHidePassword = true;

  void _onChangedPassword(String password) {
    setState(() {
      _password = password;
    });
    widget.onChanged(password);
  }

  void _togglePasswordVisibility() {
    setState(() {
      _shouldHidePassword = !_shouldHidePassword;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          onChanged: _onChangedPassword,
          decoration: _buildInputDecoration(),
          obscureText: _shouldHidePassword,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  InputDecoration _buildInputDecoration() {
    return InputDecoration(
      suffixIcon: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          _shouldHidePassword ? CustomIcons.eye_show : CustomIcons.eye_hide),
        onPressed: _togglePasswordVisibility,
      ),
      labelText: 'Password',
    );
  }
}
```

**password_field_test.dart**

```
testWidgets('should show an eye that obscures/unobscures the typed values', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      // buildWidget just wraps target in a MediaQuery/Directionality/Material
      Widget field = buildWidget(PasswordField(onChanged: (_) {}));
      String testPW = 'passwordtotest';

      await tester.pumpWidget(field);
      expect(find.byType(TextField), findsOneWidget);


      await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), testPW);
      await tester.pump();

      // These are what I've tried so far
      expect(find.text('•' * testPW.length), findsOneWidget)
      expect(find.byElementType(TextSpan))


      await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton));
      await tester.pump();

      expect(find.text(testPW), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
```

So far, I've tried following the Flutter widget testing documentation, but I am unable to find the obscured/unobscured text via `find.text('demopassword');`

I also unsuccessfully tried using a finder for the underlying EditableText and TextSpan, but I don't know how I'd target the text value even if I were able to find them. How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps the technique shown here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236046/85472) of getting the text content from a TextField widget might work for you in this case too?

Answer (score 0):

In the widget above, though visibly we are showing '*' or plain text, storage for the text would always be plain text. So, while trying to check it through the test, it will never be able to find the obscured password.
Ideally while testing obscurities we should only check for their flag status (obscureText).

Try the following modification to your test -

- Step 1: Check if the password is rendered with **obscured** text
- Step 2: Tap on the IconButton
- Step 3: Check if the password is rendered with **plain** text

```js
testWidgets('should show an eye that obscures/unobscures the typed values',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // buildWidget just wraps target in a MediaQuery/Directionality/Material
    Widget field = buildWidget(PasswordField(onChanged: (_) {}));
    String testPW = 'passwordtotest';

    await tester.pumpWidget(field);
    expect(find.byType(TextField), findsOneWidget);

    await tester.enterText(find.byType(TextField), testPW);
    await tester.pump();

    expect(
        (tester.firstWidget(find.byType(TextField)) as TextField).obscureText,
        true);

    await tester.tap(find.byType(IconButton));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(
        (tester.firstWidget(find.byType(TextField)) as TextField).obscureText,
        false);
  });
```

> Additionally, as an engineering suggestion, rather than using setState() in the code, you can actually try using ValueListenableBuilder. It is easy, avoids unnecessary state management hassles and prevents performance impact. More reference here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html

Using, ValueListenableBuilder, your build method code would look somewhat like this -

```js
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
          valueListenable: shouldHidePassword,
          builder: (context, bool value, child) {
            return TextField(
              onChanged: _onChangedPassword,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(shouldHidePassword.value
                      ? Icons.remove_red_eye_outlined
                      : Icons.remove_red_eye),
                  onPressed: () =>
                      shouldHidePassword.value = !shouldHidePassword.value,
                ),
                labelText: 'Password',
              ),
              obscureText: value,
            );
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Its cleaner and easier to maintain; while you can avoid a bunch of performance issues later!