# Flutter Testing: Retrieving values from text field

Tags: authentication, flutter, testing, dart, flutter-test

I am currently testing my login page in flutter and I want to make sure that the values I am entering are the ones being passed when I click log-in (username and password). I want to do more than just validate if the inputs are in a certain format. I would like to see if I wrote "Tom123" it returns "Tom123".  What is the best way to go about testing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter - how to get Text widget on widget test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235752/flutter-how-to-get-text-widget-on-widget-test)

Comment: The OP is asking how to retrieve the text entered in a **TextField** widget however the answer points to a post showing how to retrieve the text stored in a **Text** widget.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/widget/tap-drag) specific for this kind of test:

> ### [enterText method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/enterText.html)
>
> Give the text input widget specified by finder the focus and replace
> its content with text, as if it had been provided by the onscreen
> keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the text field's controller worked for me.

```
final textField =
          find.byType(TextField).evaluate().first.widget as TextField;
      expect(textField.controller!.text, equals("Tom123"));
```